# Limit $\lim \limits_{x\to0}{\frac{\ln(x+1)}{2^x-1}}$ wihout LHospital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to find this limit but without using L'Hospital, with which is one-liner.

$$\lim \limits_{x\to0}{\frac{\ln(x+1)}{2^x-1}}$$

Comment: I think you mean L'Hopîtal, not "LHospital". :)

Comment: @AvZ I think you mean `L'Hôpital`. `L'Hospital` is fine. A lot of French words have had the "s" removed and replaced by a circumflex over the nearest vowel. e.g. `hostel -> hôtel`.

Comment: @AvZ See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_the_circumflex_in_French#Disappearance_of_.22s.22

Comment: Well, I'm no expert on french names...

Comment: @AvZ Then don't correct people when you are wrong.

Comment: If you take a closer look at my phrasing, you'll find out that I said I think he meant to say L'Hopîtal. Besides, I don't think Hôpital means hospital here. As far as I know Hôpital was was a person.

Comment: @AvZ Si tacuisses, philosophus mansisses. Your french is, as you said yourself... Such discussions are, how to say, ..

Comment: I don't speak French at all. If only I hadn't put that arrow thing on the 'i', I'd still have plausible deniablilty

Comment: I once saw a copy of a letter written by the man himself, where he wrote it as *Lhospital* ... so I guess French spelling has changed since then anyway.

Comment: @AvZ Nope. You're still wrong.

Answer (score 2):

hint
$$\ln{(1+x)}=x+o(x),x\to 0$$
because we know
$$\dfrac{x}{x+1}<\ln{(1+x)}<x$$

$$2^x-1=\ln{2}\cdot x+o(x),x\to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Using only known limits:
$$\begin{align}&\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\ln(1 + t)}t = 1\\
&\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^t - 1}t = 1
\end{align}$$

and observing that $e^{x\ln 2} = 2^x$, rewrite as follows:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(1 + x)}{2^x - 1} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(1 + x)}{x\ln 2}\cdot \frac{x\ln 2}{e^{x\ln 2} - 1} = \frac1{\ln 2}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(1 + x)}{x}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x\ln 2}{e^{x\ln2} - 1} = \frac1{\ln 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

As $x$ goes to $0$, we have
$$\frac{\ln(x+1)}{e^{x \ln 2}-1}=\frac{x+O(x^2)}{x\ln 2+O(x^2)}\to \frac{1}{\ln 2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{2^x - 1} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x}\ln(x+1)}{\frac{1}{x}(2^x - 1)}= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x}\ln(x+1)}{\frac{1}{x}(2^x - 1)}.$$

Now, $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\ln(x+1) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln\left[(1+1/n)^n \right] = \ln(e) = 1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2^x -1}{x} = \left. \frac{d(2^x)}{dx}\right|_{x=0}=\ln(2)$$ and the result follows.

The second limit might also be one that you are expected to know independent of it being the derivative. In a sense, it follows directly from the other limit and it is certainly worth remembering.